# Download an image with an ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some files on my PHP server inside `uploads` folder. My problem is the following: *I want to send a JSON asynchronous request from my client as to choose one of these files and create with this an image element as to display it in the browser*.

**JS code**

```
 var file_name="test.jpg";        
 $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"retrieve_photo.php",
        data:{name:file_name},
        success: function(data) { 
           var new_thumb = document.createElement("img");
           document.getElementById('dragarea').appendChild(new_thumb);
          ...
        }
     })
```

**PHP code (retrieve_photo.php):**

```
<?php  
  $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $storeFolder="uploads";
  $file_name=$_POST[name];
  $files = glob($storeFolder.$ds.$file_name);                
  if ( false!==$files ) {   
      ....
  }
  header('Content-type: text/json');            
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

I do not know what to write as `$result` feeds `data` the right way. I 've tried

```
$result=readfile($storeFolder.$ds.$file_name);
```

but maybe not correctly.As to conclude **I want to use `data` as to display an image** to my browser.

Thank you

Comment: `$_POST[name]` should be `$_POST['name']` unless `name` is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will be better do something like that?:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "blabla";
$(image).on('load', function(){
//do what you want
})
```

Why do you even use AJAX? Maybe i don't understand)

Comment: It is not my choice, I have to do it with json request

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use algorithm or functions in your PHP, you can do everything by Javascript / Jquery :

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'uploads/'+ file_name)
    .on('load', function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined") {
            alert('Image not found');
        } else {
            $("#dragarea").append(img);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have to use json request. So, is there any way to get a file from server in my way?

Comment: Why do you have to use this ?

Answer (score 0):

> document.*getElementByI*('dragarea').appendChild(new_thumb);

Мaybe you mean? document.**getElementById**('dragarea').appendChild(new_thumb);

```
document.getElementById('dragarea').appendChild(new_thumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your `retrieve_photo.php`

```
$filename = "test.jpg";
    //Make sure $filename contains the appropriate path of the photo
    $size = getimagesize($filename);
    $file = $filename;
    if ($size) {
        header("Content-type:". $size['mime']);
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
```